# Extract individual frames as a buffer from a video

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, opencv, ffmpeg, base64

I'm trying to process a video using tensorflow in node.js (i.e. on the server - I don't have a web page). I need to process each frame in the video individually. I see some people are using ffmpeg to generate individual image files from the video but that seems wasteful as it creates files on the filesystem. I would prefer to grab each frame as a base64 string in memory. I've got this working using OpenCV4Node but am wondering if there are any lighter weight solutions. Is anyone already doing this? Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Maybe that if you share how your are grabbing your image from your video, people can easily see if your approach is the best one or make possible suggestions

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I'm looking for something similar.